# Error: Output field 'XXXX' is incomplete

Tags: ibm-cloud, spss-modeler, watson-studio

I have a basic SPSS Modeller flow ...

[image]

When I try to run the 'Value Bin' node I get the error:

> Error: Output field 'Value Bin' is incomplete

[image]

Value Bin is defined as this:

[image]

I shouldn't have any missing values:

[image]

[image]

What does this error message actually mean?

Sorry for all the screenshots.

---

*Update*

I updated the Derive node to a binning node and still the same issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Derive node, under **Measurement,** you need to change Range to Set.

By definition the field is Nominal so to declare it also as a Range, i.e. Continuous, confuses things. I'm not sure why the node even gives you that option but maybe it makes sense somewhere.

The error 'Output field X is incomplete' means that the type of X is not fully specified, and in this case it's because it can't make sense of something that is both nominal and continuous.

Comment: Changing to a SET fixed the issue.  Strangely, I also tried a BIN node instead of Derive, but that surprisingly didn't work.

Comment: That surprises me too. You can usually resolve such problems by adding a Type node immediately before the modeling node; you don't need to change any settings, but it will make sure that any 'incomplete' types are fully resolved before the algorithm is invoked.